# [ERROR]:Unable to set value to keychain Error Domain=com.samsoffes.sskeychain Code=-50 "errSecParam" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=errSecParam}

Tags: appcelerator-titanium, bencoding

I am using appcelerator titanium and bencoding. What could be the error with the following code? Error attached below

```
 var securely = require('bencoding.securely');
    var SecureProperties = securely.createProperties({
            secret : "hidden_dont_tell",
            identifier : "myPropertyIdentifier",
            vi : "$H@Crit1c4L",
             storageType:securely.PROPERTY_TYPE_KEYCHAIN ,
            securityLevel : securely.PROPERTY_SECURE_LEVEL_HIGH
        });
        SecureProperties.setString('String', "p4$$M0RD");
```

> [ERROR]:Unable to set value to keychain Error
>   Domain=com.samsoffes.sskeychain Code=-50 "errSecParam"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=errSecParam}

Comment: @Lakinadu Gunasekara Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use storage type as 
PROPERTY_TYPE_PREFERENCES 
instead

Comment: thanks for reply. But after using above preferences ,will it store the password into keychain.

Comment: Hello, This issue is happening only for simulator build. so you can use PROPERTY_TYPE_PREFERENCES  for use just simulator build. Password will store into keychain with PROPERTY_TYPE_KEYCHAIN , If you run this application in real device Issue. Thanks.

Comment: I have followed this link - https://github.com/benbahrenburg/Securely/issues/48  and working fine PROPERTY_TYPE_KEYCHAIN for Simulator build.

Comment: Great...if my answer helped you please accept it as the answer.